# How to change column in Matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

```
Test
N        Date Column2  
1  2015-07-15      56   
2  2015-04-17      45
```

How can I change a column with dates to a column with real numbers, I want to change each date to a number of month of date, for example `2015-07-15` change to `7`, `2014-05-13` to `5`.

Comment: Either `as.numeric(sub(".*-(.*)-.*", "\\1", x))` if you feel like practicing regex. Or if you really have a class `Date` column, `as.numeric(format(x, "%m"))`

Comment: Thank you, but I can't understand how to implement it, I hava A Matrix Sales and how can I change a colomn Date?

Comment: If you have different data-types, matrices in R are not practical (as they require the same datatype). Dataframes can accomodate multiple data types (like Dates or numeric variables).

Comment: Sale$Date[Sale$Date == %m(i)] = i 
I need something like this, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First convert to data frame:

```
as.data.frame(mat)
  N       Date Column2
1 1 2015-07-15      56
2 2 2015-04-17      45
```

Then use regular expressions to extract the relevant data:

```
newdf$Date <- as.numeric(sub(".*-(.*)-.*", "\\1", newdf$Date))
newdf
  N Date Column2
1 1    7      56
2 2    4      45
```

Regular expressions are important in many programming languages. For great tutorials and explanations, try http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

---

If you would like to work with `Date` vectors, you can try a different approach.

After converting to data frame as we did in the first step above:

```
newdf <- as.data.frame(mat)
newdf$Date <- as.Date(newdf$Date)
newdf$Date <- as.numeric(format(newdf$Date, "%m"))
```

Now if we want to subset as you indicate in the comments:

```
newdf[newdf$Date == 7,]
  N Date Column2
1 1    7      56
```

Comment: Ok you are my hero, but the last one for matrix Store1M it doesn't work 
Strore1M$Date <- as.numeric(sub(".*-(.*)-.*", "\\1", Store1M$Date))
Error in Store1M$Date : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
but for data type Store1 it works what should I do for matrix.
P.S. Thank you I tryed to find an answer for 3 hours.

Comment: It will give you that error if you did not convert to data frame. The dollar operator `$` is NOT for matrices.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help. If you feel like it solves your problem, you can accept the answer on the left.

Comment: Convert to data frame. Or if you have to use a matrix, `Store1M[, "Date"]`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
df <- data.frame(
  N=c(1,2),
  Date=c("2015-07-15","2014-04-21"),
  Column2=c(56,45)
)
df

df$Date <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(df$Date), "%m"))
```